# Route with param without value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here are my routes:

```
resources :users
```

Is it possible to get routes with a param but without value, example:

```
/users/123?cool
```

or

```
/users/123?bad
```

How should I call the routes using `UrlHelper` to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any custom params when calling the routes using the `UrlHelper`:

```
users_path(cool: true)
```

will produce the following path:

```
/users?cool=true
```